# Is it possible to attain a classified raster with several classes in just one QGIS raster calculator operation?

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-calculator

I'm using qgis' raster calculator and wanted to make a new raster (oraster) from the values of an input raster (iraster). something like:

if iraster>2 then oraster=1; if iraster >4 then oraster=2; if iraster>6 then oraster=3

all in one operation.

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 4):

There IS a way to do it in the standard raster calculator ... but it's a kludge ...

`(iraster@1 > 2) + (iraster@1 > 4) + (iraster@1 > 6)`

This does a comparison test inside each set of parentheses, returning the value '1' for each true comparison, '0' otherwise. Thus, if the raster value of a cell is 5, `(iraster@1 >2)` returns 1, `(iraster@1 > 4)` returns 1, and `(iraster@1 > 6)` returns 0 - thus giving a 'classification' of 1 + 1 + 0 = 2.

Embarrassingly ugly.

Comment: Do you mind if you could comment the code above? I... fail to see the classes?

Comment: Edited with explanation. You could probably make this work for a number of cases, but only returning boolean 0/1 for each test thus your classifications would be integers limited to 0, 1, ... etc.

Answer (score 3):

Currently the build in QGIS raster calculator does not support this. Your best bet is to take the raster into grass and use the grass r.mapcalc (there is also a nice gui for doing this visually in the grass plugins toolbox).

Tim

Comment: (ASTGTM2_N37W026_dem@1<=30)*1 + (ASTGTM2_N37W026_dem@1>30)*2 + (ASTGTM2_N37W026_dem@1>200)*3 it is really a awful syntax to reclassify a raster... I will file a ticket on the QGIS bug tracker, this is a much needed feature (allow use conditional rules).